# CTRL+c,CTRL+d, CTRL+z disable for wetty terminal in linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

How can we disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> options for wetty terminal which is integrated in linux machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Arg0n Wetty is a js library for implementing a terminal in your browser.

Comment: yeah. i will update the tag.